# Unable to connect using ssh

Tags: ssh, crash, snap, pam

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 model b, the OS is Ubuntu Mate 16, everything was working fine before.

Today I have started the rpi, I figured out I am facing a problem which occurs during boot time due to crash while loading kernel modules, ssh service is enabled, but even if I type the correct credentials that I am 100% sure are correct, now ssh says that they're incorrect, also the service of vnc is not started.

When I have plugged the rpi into the monitor I see a message that shows in Loop on console:

> "Unhandled prefetch abort: breakpoint debug exception (0x002) at
>   0x7447beda"

This is apart of syslog looks like:

```
    Mar 18 04:20:45 x systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 206 (plymouthd).
Mar 18 04:20:45 x systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
Mar 18 04:20:45 x NetworkManager[642]: <info>  [1521346845.8966] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: ready -> inactive
Mar 18 04:20:45 x kernel: [   37.431450] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)
Mar 18 04:20:46 x snapd[647]: sizeclass=16 NumSizeClasses=2_
Mar 18 04:20:46 x ModemManager[644]: <info>  Couldn't check support for device at '/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1': not supported by any plugin
Mar 18 04:20:46 x snapd[647]: fatal error: InitSizes - bad NumSizeClasses
Mar 18 04:20:46 x snapd[647]: runtime: panic before malloc heap initialized
Mar 18 04:20:46 x snapd[647]: runtime stack:
Mar 18 04:20:46 x snapd[647]: runtime.throw(0xfeaea8, 0x1e)
Mar 18 04:20:46 x snapd[647]: #011/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/panic.go:2? +0x80 fp=0x7ea3faa0 sp=0x7ea3fa94
Mar 18 04:20:46 x snapd[647]: runtime.initSizes()
Mar 18 04:20:46 x snapd[647]: #011/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/msize.go:2<8A> +0x2fc fp=0x7ea3fac8 sp=0x7ea3faa0
Mar 18 04:20:46 x snapd[647]: runtime.mallocinit()
Mar 18 04:20:46 x snapd[647]: #011/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/malloc.go:2<F5> +0x1c fp=0x7ea3fb54 sp=0x7ea3fac8
Mar 18 04:20:46 x snapd[647]: runtime.schedinit()
Mar 18 04:20:46 x snapd[647]: #011/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/proc.go:2<CD> +0x5c fp=0x7ea3fb78 sp=0x7ea3fb54
Mar 18 04:20:46 x snapd[647]: runtime.rt0_go(0x7ea3fd14, 0x76f33000, 0x7ea3fd14, 0x1, 0x6fe718, 0x76fb8000, 0xaaaaaaab, 0xc4b6dc5b, 0xccf33fe6, 0x12c, ...)
Mar 18 04:20:46 x snapd[647]: #011/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/asm_arm.s:2Y +0x8c fp=0x7ea3fbb8 sp=0x7ea3fb78
Mar 18 04:20:46 x systemd[1]: snapd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Mar 18 04:20:46 x systemd[1]: Failed to start Snappy daemon.
Mar 18 04:20:46 x systemd[1]: snapd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 18 04:20:46 x systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 18 04:20:47 x kernel: [   38.566328] Unhandled prefetch abort: breakpoint debug exception (0x002) at 0x7441ceda
Mar 18 04:20:47 x systemd[1]: snapd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 18 04:20:47 x systemd[1]: Stopped Snappy daemon.
Mar 18 04:20:47 x systemd[1]: Starting Snappy daemon...
Mar 18 04:20:50 x snapd[835]: sizeclass=16 NumSizeClasses=2_
Mar 18 04:20:50 x snapd[835]: fatal error: InitSizes - bad NumSizeClasses
Mar 18 04:20:50 x snapd[835]: runtime: panic before malloc heap initialized
Mar 18 04:20:50 x snapd[835]: runtime stack:
Mar 18 04:20:50 x snapd[835]: runtime.throw(0x1026ea8, 0x1e)
Mar 18 04:20:50 x snapd[835]: #011/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/panic.go:2? +0x80 fp=0x7e803aa0 sp=0x7e803a94
Mar 18 04:20:50 x snapd[835]: runtime.initSizes()
Mar 18 04:20:50 x snapd[835]: #011/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/msize.go:2<8A> +0x2fc fp=0x7e803ac8 sp=0x7e803aa0
Mar 18 04:20:50 x snapd[835]: runtime.mallocinit()
Mar 18 04:20:50 x snapd[835]: #011/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/malloc.go:2<F5> +0x1c fp=0x7e803b54 sp=0x7e803ac8
Mar 18 04:20:50 x snapd[835]: runtime.schedinit()
Mar 18 04:20:50 x snapd[835]: #011/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/proc.go:2<CD> +0x5c fp=0x7e803b78 sp=0x7e803b54
Mar 18 04:20:50 x snapd[835]: runtime.rt0_go(0x7e803d14, 0x76f1f000, 0x7e803d14, 0x1, 0x73a718, 0x76fa4000, 0xaaaaaaab, 0x3b4e3c89, 0x332adf34, 0x12c, ...)
Mar 18 04:20:50 x snapd[835]: #011/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/asm_arm.s:2Y +0x8c fp=0x7e803bb8 sp=0x7e803b78
Mar 18 04:20:50 x systemd[1]: snapd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Mar 18 04:20:50 x systemd[1]: Failed to start Snappy daemon.
Mar 18 04:20:50 x systemd[1]: snapd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 18 04:20:50 x systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 18 04:20:50 x systemd[1]: snapd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 18 04:20:50 x systemd[1]: Stopped Snappy daemon.
Mar 18 04:20:50 x systemd[1]: Starting Snappy daemon...
Mar 18 04:20:52 x hciattach[625]: Initialization timed out.
Mar 18 04:20:52 x hciattach[625]: bcm43xx_init
Mar 18 04:20:52 x hciattach[625]: Set Controller UART speed to 921600 bit/s
Mar 18 04:20:52 x hciattach[625]: Flash firmware /lib/firmware/BCM43430A1.hcd
Mar 18 04:20:52 x systemd[1]: hciuart.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 18 04:20:52 x systemd[1]: Failed to start Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART.
Mar 18 04:20:52 x systemd[1]: hciuart.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 18 04:20:52 x systemd[1]: hciuart.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 18 04:20:53 x snapd[837]: sizeclass=16 NumSizeClasses=2_
Mar 18 04:20:53 x snapd[837]: fatal error: InitSizes - bad NumSizeClasses
Mar 18 04:20:53 x snapd[837]: runtime: panic before malloc heap initialized
Mar 18 04:20:53 x snapd[837]: runtime stack:
Mar 18 04:20:53 x snapd[837]: runtime.throw(0x1024ea8, 0x1e)
Mar 18 04:20:53 x snapd[837]: #011/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/panic.go:2? +0x80 fp=0x7eb44aa0 sp=0x7eb44a94
Mar 18 04:20:53 x snapd[837]: runtime.initSizes()
```

in  auth.log

```
    Mar 18 04:20:24 x systemd-logind[645]: New seat seat0.
Mar 18 04:20:48 x sshd[1271]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Mar 18 04:20:48 x sshd[1271]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Mar 18 04:35:41 x sshd[1271]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
Mar 18 04:35:41 x sshd[1271]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Mar 18 04:35:41 x sshd[1271]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Mar 18 04:35:53 x sshd[1271]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
Mar 18 04:35:53 x sshd[1271]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Mar 18 04:35:53 x sshd[1271]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Mar 18 05:01:01 x CRON[3341]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_unix.so): /lib/security/pam_unix.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mar 18 05:01:01 x CRON[3341]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_unix.so
Mar 18 05:01:01 x CRON[3341]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_permit.so): /lib/security/pam_permit.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mar 18 05:01:01 x CRON[3341]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_permit.so
Mar 18 05:01:01 x CRON[3341]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_loginuid.so): /lib/security/pam_loginuid.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mar 18 05:01:01 x CRON[3341]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_loginuid.so
Mar 18 05:01:01 x CRON[3341]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_env.so): /lib/security/pam_env.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mar 18 05:01:01 x CRON[3341]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_env.so
Mar 18 05:01:01 x CRON[3341]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_umask.so): /lib/security/pam_umask.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mar 18 05:01:01 x CRON[3341]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_umask.so
Mar 18 05:01:01 x CRON[3341]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_limits.so): /lib/security/pam_limits.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mar 18 05:01:01 x CRON[3341]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_limits.so
Mar 18 05:17:01 x CRON[3905]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_unix.so): /lib/security/pam_unix.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mar 18 05:17:01 x CRON[3905]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_unix.so
Mar 18 05:17:01 x CRON[3905]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_permit.so): /lib/security/pam_permit.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mar 18 05:17:01 x CRON[3905]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_permit.so
Mar 18 05:17:01 x CRON[3905]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_loginuid.so): /lib/security/pam_loginuid.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mar 18 05:17:01 x CRON[3905]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_loginuid.so
Mar 18 05:17:01 x CRON[3905]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_env.so): /lib/security/pam_env.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mar 18 05:17:01 x CRON[3905]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_env.so
Mar 18 05:17:01 x CRON[3905]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_umask.so): /lib/security/pam_umask.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mar 18 05:17:01 x CRON[3905]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_umask.so
Mar 18 05:17:01 x CRON[3905]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_limits.so): /lib/security/pam_limits.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mar 18 05:17:01 x CRON[3905]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_limits.so
Mar 18 06:01:01 x CRON[5443]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_unix.so): /lib/security/pam_unix.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mar 18 06:01:01 x CRON[5443]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_unix.so
Mar 18 06:01:01 x CRON[5443]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_permit.so): /lib/security/pam_permit.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mar 18 06:01:01 x CRON[5443]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_permit.so
```

So as you can see snapd crashes and restarted itself causing the system be unstable.

Comment: What’s your question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: im unable to access into my rpi, it boots and in fanile stage the message error keeps printing in a cercle way, i guess this error affects the ssh login failure?

Comment: since im unable to access into the machine, i have mounted the usb stick which contains the OS into another linux computer in order to read the boot logs

Comment: Neither of your comments contains a question. Even the sentence with the question mark is not actually a question and I see no implied question either beyond "How do I fix this?". Unfortunately you mention multiple issues so I can't tell for sure what "this" might be here. Could you please [edit] your post to clarify what you want to know or solve? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster seriously ?! my question is 100% clear ! i cannot log into my RPI using ssh !

Comment: "I am facing a problem which occurs during boot time due to crash while loading kernel modules" – That part doesn't sound like an SSH issue to me.

Comment: This syslogd message may provide a clue:  "Mar 18 04:20:45 x kernel: [   37.431450] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)"   See this link for discussion:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48329/undervoltage-warning-despite-decent-power-supply

Comment: @TonyB thank you ,this is just an information ... it was showing in the past when the system was stable, so i don't think this is the source of the problem

Comment: It says your power supply is marginal at best, or you have external devices that are "sucking" too much power...

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned in comments `Mar 18 04:20:45 x kernel: [   37.431450] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)` tells the tale. Unplugging power hungry devices from the USB ports will likely solve your problem. The Pi power supplies will not power the Pi AND USB devices very well. This is especially a problem when attempting to power an external drive via a USB port, but other power hungry devices can also create this issue. Most of the Pi PSU's that I've seen provide less than 3 amps. While a USB port typically draws [between 1/2 and 1 amp](https://superuser.com/questions/690074/what-is-the-power-output-of-a-usb-port) this can rapidly add up and cause problems on the Pi. According to [the specifications](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs) the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B has a reommended PSU that supplies 2.5A    with a max power draw from the USB ports of 1.2A Exceeding the electrical specifications of a device or even hitting maximum can and will cause problems. [A voltage sag (or dip)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_sag) of even 10% can and will cause issues. While this question is likely to be considered off-topic, I voted that it remain open due to the likelihood of it being useful to future users of the site.